# Visual brush snap to device pixels

Tags: wpf, vb.net, canvas

I have an application with a small overview window to navigate the canvas faster. On that window I display a flowchart with relations and decisions , etc... When the flowchart grows the overview window doesn't display the line's anymore this is because the line thickness is less then 1 px.

I've already tried to set the snap to device pixels on the lines,the canvas with the brush on it,but without success.

Is there an option to make the brush display the lines even if they are less thin then 1 px?

Comment: So what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have essentially a minimap to navigate your Window. In which case, have a look at rendering controls as bitmaps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx

It should be pretty simple to render your canvas and display it in the overview window.